# string split with regular expression

Tags: swift

> <concept info="[{"Concept":"KUKA","Class":"roboterModell","Label":"KUKA"},{"Concept":"KUKA","Class":"roboterHersteller","Label":"KUKA"}]">KUKA_Typenübersicht_Produktkatalog_DE.pdf

unable to split string using "<concept (.+?)>(.+?)" regular expression
am looking for KUKA_Typenübersicht_Produktkatalog_DE and .pdf

Comment: Please check the example I have created: https://regex101.com/r/Qvk7Yk/1. The groups you need are 2 and 3. Have in mind this regex might be absolutely wrong based on your requirements or the data that comes in! Please provide more details about what patterns or rules your input strings follow, so I can provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: Add more example!

Answer (score 0):

`text.split(separator: ">").last` gives *KUKA_Typenübersicht_Produktkatalog_DE and .pdf*

```
let text = """
           <concept info="[{"Concept":"KUKA","Class":"roboterModell","Label":"KUKA"},{"Concept":"KUKA","Class":"roboterHersteller","Label":"KUKA"}]">KUKA_Typenübersicht_Produktkatalog_DE.pdf
           """

text.split(separator: ">").last
```

Comment: "KUKA_Typenübersicht_Produktkatalog_DE</concept" and .pdf are splitting, thanks for responce